# Socket creation (::socket) fails on Windows - error 10038 (WSAENOTSOCKET)

Tags: sockets, winapi, winsock2

We're seeing very strange behavior in Windows application on some systems. Socket creation all of a sudden begins to fail with error 10038. This happens on attempt to allocate a socket with Windows API, before any connections on it take place:

```
s = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if (s == (SOCKET) -1) {
    // WSAGetLastError() returns 10038 here (WSANOTSOCKET)
}
```

Sometimes the program with this code works fine for hours. When this failure occurs, all subsequent attempts to create sockets fail also with the same error. When the process is restarted, it then works once, and fails again.

How is this even possible ? Microsoft doesn't mention WSANOTSOCKET as error condition for [::socket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740506(v=vs.85).aspx) failure, and it doesn't make any sense.

I tried examining the running program with [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) and Process Monitor, and there is nothing that stands out. The process does not have too many handles, and the overall number of TCP connections on the system is small. 
There are no obvious third-party network layers in the TCP stack, and we tried to exclude everything except IPv4, and that didn't help. There is nothing in Event Log, and the system otherwise behaves normally.

The OS is Windows 8.1 Embedded.

Comment: There's no reason you'd see this with the information given. When I see "impossible" errors happening in a seemingly random way, I think internal corruption of some sort. Heap corruption, previous incorrect socket calls destabilized the API somehow, another thread is interfering... lots and lots of possibilities.

Comment: On a side note, `if (s == (SOCKET) -1)` should be `if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)` instead.